# problem with changing jquery element values

Tags: php, jquery, html

Ive got a table were the user can click on a row and the row id is posted using jquery. The data associated with the row id is placed in a session then a form pops up (again using jquery) with the values but when the form is closed and I click another row the values do not change. Can't figure out a way round it!

Comment: Where is the `getData` function called? Where and when is the "row" click event set up?

Comment: I see no click handlers on that form? how are you attaching them? and where? Is this form in a loop, because it stands now, it would have only one row...

Comment: no, when user clicks a row the form pops up with the revelant data @Marc B

Comment: have edited and included more code @Nate Pinchot

Answer (score 0):

I just want to understand this properly: if I click on the row with the ID "TOWN_EDIT" then the value of that row should be set to its ID (in this case, "TOWN_EDIT").  Is that correct?

If that's the behavior you're looking for, you have to set the value of the $("#TOWN_EDIT") element at some point, like this:

```
$("#TOWN_EDIT").val( "TOWN_EDIT" ); // or however you'd like to specify the value
```

So, once the POST response comes back successfully, make sure to update your values.

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding things, or if you have a demo I can check out.

Comment: no I don't think it'll work, because I'm using a session variable to store the array of data